# DataTables 1.9.4 - Limiting Results

Tags: php, mysql, session, datatable

I am using DataTables-1.9.4 with server-side processing and everything is working great, but my table is returning EVERYTHING from the table! That's a total of 3,147 entries, growing daily...

Example: [www.hunterpdx.com/metro_new_copy/view-reports-test.php](http://www.hunterpdx.com/metro_new_copy/view-reports-test.php)

Is there a way to limit the return to show data specifically associated with a particular
 `user: WHERE company = $_SESSION['company']?`
I'm certain this can be done, but I've spent days on this and have gotten nowhere...

I'm using the basic initialization code (even left the table ID the same):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "../server_side/scripts/server_processing.php"
    } );
} );
```

The only things I've changed on the server_processing.php file are the aColumns array and the database connection information:

```
<?php
    /* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
     * Easy set variables
     */

    /* Array of database columns which should be read and sent back to DataTables. Use a space where
     * you want to insert a non-database field (for example a counter or static image)
     */
    $aColumns = array( 'company', 'bldg', 'report', 'freq', 'report_date', 'file_path' );

    /* Indexed column (used for fast and accurate table cardinality) */
    $sIndexColumn = "report_id";

    /* DB table to use */
    $sTable = "uploads";

    /* Database connection information */
    $gaSql['user']       = "root";
    $gaSql['password']   = "";
    $gaSql['db']         = "members";
    $gaSql['server']     = "localhost";
```

I'm assuming it has to do something with this portion of server_processing.php:

```
/*
 * Filtering
 * NOTE this does not match the built-in DataTables filtering which does it
 * word by word on any field. It's possible to do here, but concerned about efficiency
 * on very large tables, and MySQL's regex functionality is very limited
 */
$sWhere = "";
if ( isset($_GET['sSearch']) && $_GET['sSearch'] != "" )
{
    $sWhere = "WHERE (";
    for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
    {
        $sWhere .= "`".$aColumns[$i]."` LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string( $_GET['sSearch'] )."%' OR ";
    }
    $sWhere = substr_replace( $sWhere, "", -3 );
    $sWhere .= ')';
}

/* Individual column filtering */
for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
{
    if ( isset($_GET['bSearchable_'.$i]) && $_GET['bSearchable_'.$i] == "true" && $_GET['sSearch_'.$i] != '' )
    {
        if ( $sWhere == "" )
        {
            $sWhere = "WHERE ";
        }
        else
        {
            $sWhere .= " AND ";
        }
        $sWhere .= "`".$aColumns[$i]."` LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['sSearch_'.$i])."%' ";
    }
}
```

The goal here is to make sure that the user only sees data associated with his company (even when using the built-in filtering search):

```
WHERE company = '$_SESSION['company']'
```

The site going live is literally hinging on this being done, so I'm in serious need of help!
Can this be done? And how?

Comment: do you have session_start() directive on the page that is making use of $_SESSION variables ? Also can you echo your final query statement $sWhere and see what you get there ?

Comment: I do indeed! view-reports-test.php includes a session_start() at the top of the page and initializes $_SESSION['company'] and some others.  If I echo our $_SESSION['company'] on view-reports-test.php I get the correct output.

Comment: I'm not sure where to echo $sWhere and get any results...I've tried on the view-reports-test.php and on the server_processing.php, but I'm not finding the output...

Comment: update: it works with the workaround `$sWhere = "WHERE company='Adidas'";`  I must be doing something wrong with the `$company = $_SESSION['company']` variable, because `$sWhere ="WHERE compay='".$company."'";` returns no results.

Comment: try where company = '".$_SESSION['company']."' (single quote then double quote and end it in that order)

Comment: That is also returning "No matching records found".

Comment: then maybe there are no matching records for this particular case ? Like I mentioned before, maybe you should echo your final query statement that is generated and see what does that look like. That would be helpful.

Comment: ok - when `$sWhere = "WHERE company='adidas'";` it echoes:
> WHERE company = 'adidas'
when `$sWhere = "WHERE company='".$_SESSION['company']."'";` it echoes:
> WHERE company = ' '

Comment: SO! You were right with the first comment and I failed to follow through...I called `session_start();` on view-reports-test.php, but did NOT call a `session_start();` on server_processing.php.  Of course, now it's properly echoing out 'adidas' when calling the session variable.  THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks go out to @Maximus2012 for walking me through this one!  The answer was simple:

Call `session_start();` at the top of the server_processing.php page!

To filter for the specific session, I set a user-specific variable below the session start:

```
$userCompany = $_SESSION['company'];
```

and then called the variable in the filtering portion of the code by changing the first:

```
$sWhere = "";
```

to

```
$sWhere = "WHERE company = '".$userCompany."'";
```

Finally, to make sure the search filter didn't get around the initial filter, I changed the

```
$sWhere .= ')';
```

to

```
$sWhere .= ") AND company = '".$userCompany."'";
```